# Looking for a resource which provides django templates

Tags: django, resources, django-templates

I'm pretty handy with django and python but I'm terrible at the "visual" aspect of the web-design.  Even after quite a bit of google-ing I haven't been able to find any sort of resource that has download-able templates complete with css, images, etc. that could be used to set up a basic website easily.

I'm looking for examples beyond the 5-line examples that you find in most tutorials ... I'm looking for something with the general nav-bar across the top, various content-blocks to over-ride through subclassing, footers, etc.

I've worked with others on django projects but always on the "coding side".  I want to do my own project.  I've set up all of the views, models, "business logic", I just cant get off the ground with the design section.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**: Just to be a little more clear. I'm looking for designs (open licensed) ... akin to Wordpress themes. If you have a resource of just themes I can probably mung them into a django template but if you know of something that already provides them as templates I'd prefer that.

Comment: I suspect that you don't need help on the templates, you need help with design in general. Try looking online for nifty designs you might like and implement them with the template system. I'm sure if you can learn Python/Django, you can figure out the syntax.

Comment: exactly ... i don't really need help with the template system or using them ... I'm looking for some designs.  If they come in pure HTML I could probably mung them into a django template.  But I could still use a few links for those as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had some luck in the past with sites like [OpenDesigns](http://www.opendesigns.org/) and [FreeCSSTemplates](http://www.freecsstemplates.org/) -- they offer (mostly) CC-licensed HTML templates; you'll have to add the Django template stuff yourself. As James pointed out though, most of them will get you up and running, but you almost always want to take things a step further.

My advice: build up a small library of re-usable templates (using stuff from the above sites), get real comfortable editing HTML and CSS (because you **will** edit HTML and CSS), then find some kickass designers (preferably local) and get real friendly with them. Perhaps you can trade favors; you do some coding work for them, for free, and in return they do some design work for you. I've found that even if you have to pay, a good designer is well worth the money (seriously, who wants to spend their time testing sites in IE6?).

Good luck with your search though -- I, for one, would love to see your findings.

Comment: +1 "find a kickass designer" I work with a woman who has amazing design skills (she was classically trained back in hardcopy days) and a real sense of color and tone. I helped her wade into HTML/CSS (and I sometimes do a little JS for her) and she is my go-to-girl for everything from palette choices, to fonts, to icon graphics, etc. It's a very symbiotic relationship.

Comment: hopefully in a month or so I'll have made a better answer for this one ;)

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this is an area that is completely lacking.  I've been looking for a django project, perhaps a meta-django project is a good way to go ;).

Maybe if designers could upload a set of templates against a simple and well defined set of models.  They could upload a "main.html", "object_list.html", "object_detail.html", a css file and a few images.  This would be something akin to the [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) project.

I've setup a github repository here: http://github.com/JudoWill/DjangoTemplateRepository. Feel free to log into the project and modify the wiki with requests.

The idea being to give newbies a starting point and a few examples for making their django website.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this has got nothing to do with django templates, your question sounds more of a design and markup. There are couple of css framework like [Blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/), [960](http://960.gs/), [YAML](http://www.yaml.de/en/).

Comment: almost what I'm looking for, but I was hoping to find something that had "all" of the pieces of a web-design.  Images, css, html, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to be able to find what you're looking for unfortunately - I have the same problem.

Wordpress templates can assume a fairly well-known data model - every Wordpress installation uses the same predictable table names, every (say) blog page has a well-defined set of data that will be passed to the template - and even the plugins have only a limited number of plugin points to add extra data.

By contrast, your Django app could contain *anything*. I could provide you a pretty template, but unless the data I use in the template exactly matches your data model, it's not going to be useful. I could make the template very very generic - eg, just have it display the variable called 'form' if it's present, iterate over 'messages' if any are present at the top of the page, display a 'footer' at the bottom etc - but it will take you about 20 seconds before you want to customise the display of that form, and then you're back editing your own templates.

I think that the closest thing you're going to find are UI libraries like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) which can handle a lot of the work of making your UI look snazzy.

I'd like to be proven wrong though, it would save me going through the same trial as you're going through now.

Update: On re-reading this, it occurred to me that you're looking for a CMS, which Django is not. Two seconds of work with Google revealed [django CMS](http://www.django-cms.org/). I haven't tried it, but maybe that's closer to what you're looking for? The django wiki has a [comparison table](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CMSAppsComparison) of various django-based CMS solutions

Comment: I can plug my stuff into some arbitrary template ... or at least modify a template to take my models ... I just need something to modify :)