# TinyMCE, PHP and MySQL: security and escaping questions

Tags: php, mysql, html, tinymce

I'm implementing TinyMCE for a client so they can edit front-end content via a simple, familiar interface in their site's admin panel.

I have never used TinyMCE before but notice that you are able to insert whatever markup you want and it will be happily saved off to the MySQL database, assuming you don't escape the contents of the TinyMCE  before running it through your query.

You can even insert single quotes and have it break your SQL query entirely.

But of course, when I do escape the contents, benign presentational stuff like paragraph tags get converted to HTML entities and so the whole point of the WYSIWYG editor is defeated, because the entities are spat back out when it comes to displaying the stored content on the front-end.

So is there a way I can "selectively escape" content from TinyMCE, to keep the innocent tags like P and BR but get rid of dangerous ones like SCRIPT, IFRAME, etc.? I really don't want to have to manually encode and decode them using str_replace() or whatever, but I'd rather not give my client a gaping security hole either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried htmlpurifier? works wonders. Its caveats; big and slow, but the best you can have.

http://htmlpurifier.org .

Answer (score 2):

Sorry Dude, I'd say this a question for the authors of TinyMCE, so I suggest you ask at: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/enterprise/support.php ... I'm sure they'll be only to happy to answer (for a small fee), and I suspect this may even be one of there FAQ's.

It's just that I'd guess you'd be very lucky if you hit another TinyMCE-user (let alone an authorative one) on stack-overflow, a "general programming forum"... although I notice there are currently 837 questions tagged "tinymce" on this forum; have you tried searching through them? Maybe there's a pointer in one of those?

Cheers. Keith.

EDIT: Yep, [Making user-made HTML templates safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357750/making-user-made-html-templates-safe) is more or less the same question posed in different words, and it has (what looks to ignorant me) a couple of answers which posit practical solutions. I just searched stack overflow for "Tiny MCE html security".

Answer (score 2):

That's like complaining that you can write naughty words in Microsoft Word, and that Word should filter them for you. Or complain to GM that they build cars that then get used as escape vehicles in bank robberies. TinyMCE's job is to be an online editor, not to be the content police.

If you need to ban certain tags, then remove them when the document's submitted by using `strip_tags()`. Or better yet, HTMLpurifier for a more bullet-proof sanitization. If embedded quotes are breaking your SQL, then why weren't you passing the submitted document through `mysql_real_escape_string()` or using PDO prepared queries first? MCE has no idea what the server-side handling is going to be, nor should it care at all. It's up to you to decide how to handle the data, because only you know what its ultimate purpose is going to be.

In any case, remember that all those editors work on the client side. You can make TinyMCE as bulletproof and as strict an editor as you want, but it's still running on the client. Nothing says a malicious user can't bypass it entirely and submit all the embedded quotes and bad tags they want. The ultimate responsibility for cleaning the data HAS to fall on your code running on the server, as it's the last line of defense, and the only one that can ensure the database remains pristine. Anything else is lipstick on a pig.